# Eclipse Quick Fix shows no suggestion available

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) with OpenJDK8 on Mac os Catalina 10.15.6.

I used to  use quick fix frequently to make try-catch statement, but one day I got this error message below.
[image]
and I have never got to use quick fix til now.

Whenever I try to use quick fix, it always shows me 'no suggestion available'.

So I did some research about this issue,tried every solution on stack overflow unfortunately they all didn't work.

However,I found [this official eclipse site](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.text.git/commit/?id=301800e75274f26d94d01da866550c188f0d8eb1) that dealing with the bug that I'm struggling with.

I have read it all but I have no idea what to do with this.

+) UPDATE 
I uninstalled Code Recommenders via Eclipse Marketplace. 
I also deleted metadata of it.

Comment: Get a fresh Eclipse. Code Recommenders does not exist anymore. Your Eclipse is 9 releases behind. Please check if you missed updating before asking. The mentioned link refers to a commit and is not related. And I guess you talk about the content assist (Ctrl+Space) and not Quick Fix (Ctrl+1).

Comment: I updated my Eclipse but nothing has changed. I used to use Quick Fix(by hovering on the text or `Comm + 1`) to use generate 'create method' or 'try-catch'.

Comment: Did you try a fresh workspace? You missed too many releases which might requiring a new workspace and better use also a fresh installation instead of upgrading your retro Eclipse.